# In pandas, why does tz_convert change the timezone used from EST to LMT?

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, pytz

In the script below, Why are **tz** and **tz2** are different?

```
import pandas
import pytz
tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
t = pandas.Timestamp('2014-03-03 08:05:39.216809')
tz2 = t.tz_localize(pytz.UTC).tz_convert(tz).tz
```

In this case, **tz** displays as:

```
<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>
```

But **tz2** displays as:

```
<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>
```

Shouldn't pandas honor the timezone I pass in to **tz_convert**?  (Is this perhaps a known bug?)

Update:

This is more of a question about pytz it seems.  The behavior that still confuses me (but likely has a clear explanation) is why are following different?

```
tz
<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>

tz.localize(t).tzinfo
<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are NOT the same.

`pytz.timezone(...)` gives you the most recent timezone! (as of your pytz package date).

Older version of pytz installed

```
In [47]: pytz.__version__
Out[47]: '2012j'

In [48]: pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
Out[48]: <DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>
```

Latest version installed

```
In [2]: pytz.__version__
Out[2]: '2014.4'

In [3]: pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
Out[3]: <DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>
```

Pandas handles this correctly, you can do it with a datetime directly like this

```
pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').localize(datetime.datetime(2012,1,1))
```

The timezone definition have recently changed to use LMT (local-mean-time). This doesn't matter as you when you localize to the dates that you are using they will be in the correct time zone.

So in answer to your question, `tz2` is correct as it localizes to a time zone that is correct for its date, while `tz` is 'correct' for the current date.

Comment: Are you saying that the timezone of `t.tz_localize(pytz.UTC).tz_convert(tz).tz` depends on the value of `t`?  I can see that as reasonable, but I've tried a variety of `t` values, including today's date.  None gives the **LMT** value.  I agree this has become a question about pytz behavior rather than pandas behavior.

Comment: absolutely it depends on t, e.g. thing about what happens day before and day after a daylight savings day change, you change from EST to EDT. you need a very current version of ``pytz`` (e.g. 2014.3) I think is when ``US/Central`` time changed IIRC (well the definition changed).

Comment: I see.  It does make sense that the output timezone after localize would be different, as you say with EST vs. EDT.  Thanks.

Comment: @D.A.: `LMT` is not the most recent timezone. It is the opposite. It is the oldest timezone that is used before 1902. A single pytz timezone contains multiple data for several `tzinfo` objects. Ignore EST, LMT in the default `repr()`; it is an implementation detail that means nothing. Use a date to get a particular tzinfo name: `pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').tzname(datetime(2012,1,1))`.

Answer (score 3):

This is `pytz`'s workaround for the fact that `datetime.tzinfo`, the abstract class that represents the interface between time zone objects and `datetime.datetime` objects, is expected to be able to discover **the** offset of a time zone given only the local time, which is not in general possible because some local times are ambiguous on account of offset changes caused by Daylight Saving Time or other governmental action.

The purpose of `localize` is to take a local time *and an additional `is_dst` parameter* and return an unambiguous `datetime.datetime` with a time zone object that is tailored to give the correct offset for that time.  But a `pytz` time zone that isn't the result of localizing a time knows it can't always give the correct offset, so it doesn't try very hard-- instead, it just defaults to the first entry in the Zoneinfo database for that time.  In the case of `US/Eastern`, that's just local mean time in New York (hence those crazy four minutes).  You can get that same offset by localizing an early enough time:

```
In [28]: pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').localize(datetime.datetime(1901, 1, 1))
Out[28]: datetime.datetime(1901, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)
```

I do not know why `pytz` version 2012j exhibits different behavior, but I would guess that either the historical entries were added to Zoneinfo sometime in the past two years, or that at some point in that period unlocalized `pytz` time zones switched from a (sometimes subtly wrong) guess at the correct offset in Zoneinfo to the (obviously wrong) oldest offset in Zoneinfo.

Once [PEP 431](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0431/) is finished, `datetime.tzinfo` methods will take `is_dst` parameters where appropriate and `pytz` will be able to implement time zones that do the right thing without having the user jump though `localize` and `normalize` hoops.